# Fiddler is not capturing web request from Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, fiddler

I am new to Fiddler. On my PC, the Fiddler can capture web request sent from IE, but not Firefox. Is there any settings I should look at?

I turn on All Processes, and Capturing, but it still does NOT capture reqest from Firefox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also get the [FiddlerHook plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fiddlerfox/?src=search) for Firefox that lets you handle how you want traffic to be routed through Fiddler

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly, this should get installed atuomatically when the Fiddler installer is run.

Comment: thanks. You are right. FiddlerHook also installed with fiddler. I installed fiddler, but forgot to restart firefox. it works now, like http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/addons/fiddlerhook/.

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem.
For solve it I simply change Firefox setting to `Use system settings of proxy`.
I hope, this will be enough for correct Fiddler work.

**UPDATE**

As @Ed Birm has clarified you can find it here:

> `Options` > `Advanced` > `Network` tab > `Settings` button in Connection > Select
>   `Use system proxy settings` > `OK`

Or type in URL `about:preferences#advanced` and then find `Network` tab > `Settings` in Connection > and select `Use system proxy settings` and `OK`.

**UPDATE 2**

For newer versions of Firefox go to:

> `Options` > `General` > `Network Proxy` > `Setting` button > `Use system proxy settings` > `OK`

Comment: More precisely, Tools, Options, Advanced, Network tab, "Settings" button for the Connection section, check "use System Proxy settings" option and save.  Thanks Bohdan!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Fiddler as a HTTP PROXY. Then, set your Firefox Network settings to use a Proxy, and on the connection parameters, use Fiddler's default port, which is: 8888.

Take a look at [this](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp) document.

Comment: thanks. I installed fiddler, but forgot to restart firefox. it works now, like http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/addons/fiddlerhook/

Comment: That's what I did, but port 3128 to don't need to change proxy settings. Just start one proxy or other, ie squid3.

Answer (score 5):

For recent versions of Fiddler, installing FiddlerHook manually is no longer necessary. However, you still need to set up the proxy and certificate for Fiddler in Firefox. [This blog post explains those steps](http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/04/01/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler).

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue... have a read of Teleriks blog [Configuring Firefox for Fiddler](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-04-01/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler)

For me the solution was to set FireFox to use "Use system proxy settings"